# Blocked from editing DataGridView record

Tags: c#, datagridview, edit

Is it possible to block duplicate records, but also edit a selected record? I am working on something similar to this.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egUcG.png)

When I have numerous records and I update the 2nd or 3rd one, I expect a warning whenever I try to use the first record's ID; that is working nicely. However, whenever I try to edit the first record's name, city, etc, the duplicate ID error pops up, since I did not alter the ID; it is counting itself as a duplicate. No idea what to do. I tried using breakpoints, but I am not seeing anything of interest. Thanks.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProfiles.SelectedCells.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record was selected to update.");
        }

        else {
            for (int row = 0; row < dgvProfiles.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < dgvProfiles.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    if (dgvProfiles.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null &&
                      dgvProfiles.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.Equals(txtEmail.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate email was entered.");
                        return;
                    }

                    else if (dgvProfiles.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null &&
                      dgvProfiles.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.Equals(txtID.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate ID was entered.");
                        return;

                    }
                }
            }
            DataGridViewRow newDataRow = dgvProfiles.Rows[indexRow];
            newDataRow.Cells[0].Value = txtID.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[1].Value = txtName.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[4].Value = txtEmail.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[5].Value = txtCity.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[6].Value = cbxState.Text;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question but you don't need to search every column of every row - you know that the Id is in column zero so just check the cells in that column, and the same for email. As it is currently, if _any cell_ matches the ID value then it counts as a duplicate.

Comment: Seems like you should only be checking for ID dupes (and its not clear where those come from) when you Add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using the [Validation events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Validating);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

And if you bind your DataGridView to a DataSet it will be easier to walk the values in the DataSet to find duplicates.  See [DataSource property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataSource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).